# How to show pretty colored and collapsable json in MVC.Core

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-core-mvc

First of all, this is for an experiment, so I am not looking for a nice super compatible solution :)

I have a table with two columns, the first one have an image and the second one JSon.
I would like the JSon to be colored and expandable, since it can be really big

I would like something like this:

[image]

This is my current code, which produces a proper indented json, but not colored or expandable:

```
<div>
    <table style="width:100%; border-spacing: 50px;border-collapse: separate;">
        @{
            ProcessedImageViewModel[] processedImages = ViewBag.ProcessedImages;

            foreach (ProcessedImageViewModel image in processedImages)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:50%; vertical-align:top">
                        <img style="width:100%" src="@image.FilePath" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <pre><code>
                           <p>@image.OcrText</p>  // THIS-IS-A-BIG-JSON
                        </code></pre>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

What is the easiest library and how can i use it from MVC to add such panels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the easiest library and how can i use it from MVC to add such panels?

To achieve your requirement, you can try following code snippet with [Renderjson js library](https://github.com/caldwell/renderjson).

```
<table style="width:100%; border-spacing: 50px;border-collapse: separate;">
    @{
        ProcessedImageViewModel[] processedImages = ViewBag.ProcessedImages;
        foreach (ProcessedImageViewModel image in processedImages)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="width:50%; vertical-align:top">
                    <img style="width:100%" src="@image.FilePath" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="jsoncontainer">
                        @image.OcrText
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

JS code

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".jsoncontainer").each(function () {
            var data = $(this).html();

            $(this).empty();
            $(this).append(
                renderjson(JSON.parse(data))
            );
        })
    })
</script>
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thank you! :)